# Angelic Protection

Tags: cryptic-crosswords

*Instructions:*  Answers are entered normally in the grid, but there are clashes.  Some clues contain extra letters in the wordplay that are not entered in the grid; when taken in order they provide instructions on how to resolve the clashes.  After resolution solvers must identify a cryptic representation of an event.  Clue numbers without extra letters in the wordplay may be treated similarly (but not identically) to obtain a relevant detail.

The green tick requires the event and the detail.

[image: Grid]

**Across:**

1.Keep away from light: dish contains base fish (8)

7.Obsolete record two girls put together (8)

9.Show how to behave... (3)

10....in Bali. By appearance, it's another country (5)

11.Arranges incoherent ditties (6)

15.Stop short de Gaulle's night of tedium (5)

16.That is essentially wrong and inflexible (4)

17.Leader of two kings' dynasty (4)

18.Hunter versus men beheading big cat (5)

19.Poisonous river overcomes me? It's what LD50 tells you (8)

**Down:**

1.Ruling party of 8s lawyers: first one in the hot-tub is tense (8)

2.Conferencier routinely found in the middle of bull-ring (8)

3.Robust computer from 2001? (3)

4.Incompatible saline mixture (5)

5.Kids's informal claim to fish this way (3)

6.Pure (no way modified) artillery (8)

8.Middle-east gentleman bearing up in synthetic clothing(6)

12.Take away 19 using first drug introduced to first of 10 (5)

13.I mind ring-tailed (twice) and short-tailed lemur(5)

14.Timeless sequence of movements of itself (3)

17.Snap obtrusively religious recording (3)

Comment: The "extra letters" - does this mean, for example, the cryptic portion of a clue suggests an answer of enumeration 6, but the word in the grid (and the definition part of the clue) is only of enumeration 5, so one of the 6 letters is omitted?

Comment: @Duncan the enumeration given is for the grid entry and the definition part of the clue.  The wordplay part of the clue has an extra letter that is not entered in the grid

Comment: Okay, that's what I was thinking. And by "clashes" do you mean that there are some intersections of across and down answers where the interesected letter does not match?

Comment: @Duncan yes, a clash is where two different letters are required for the same cell.  A resolution is a way of picking one of them, or some way of deducing a different entry (not always a letter!) in that cell

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Completed grid:

> [image]

Clue explanations are [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IJ2NspSszMEolWGyQ_GDz0b6YtDjC80GncT8Ai-oc9A/edit?usp=sharing).

The missing letters spell:

> `LETTER VALUES SUMMED`. Summing the two clashing letters mod-26 gives IRAQ reading across the clashing slots.

The event is

> the **Iraqi invasion**, which started the [Iran-Iraq War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iran%E2%80%93Iraq_War) - you can see in row 6 of the grid, IRAQ (the location of the clashes) has literally *invaded* IRAN, so we have `IR(IRAQ)AN`. This puzzle was posted on September 22nd, the 37th anniversary of the event.

In the grid we can see other related words, some of which could be related to the "relevant detail":

> The BA'ATHIST party ruled Iraq at the time. SYRIA and LIBYA (two of the three un-extra-letter-having entries) had allied with Iran. Other potentially relevant words include WEAPON(RY), (ti)DIES, and ALIEN. (ACT is the third entry that does not have an extra letter, but it could be referring to any number of things.)

The "relevant detail" may be that:

> the modified clue numbers are 8, 9, and 10, and the year that the invasion happened was 1980. (I note that this makes "SYRIAN ACT inside LIBYA", though I can't think of any particular act this may be referring to.)

Comment: Grid fill is right, well done!  You've only resolved the clashes so far, you've not found the cryptic representation yet, but you're on the right lines.  There was a specific reason it was posted yesterday (22nd September) which might help you.
For your comments on the clues -- thank-you :)

In 18, men is OR is "Ordinary Regiments" (it's standard in this kind of crossword so I didn't think anything of using it).  The river ambiguity in 19 is resolved by the phrase the extra letters spell.  For 8 the abbrev. is in the dictionary and on clothing labels, so I didn't think it was uncommon.

Comment: @postmortes- the answer has been updated with the event and things that *could* be the relevant detail. I'm not quite sure yet, though - the word ACT has me stumped as to what it could mean.

Comment: Everything's right, and you have all the information you need to get the last detail.  The instructions are explicit about what yields the final detail :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's my progress so far.

Across:

1.Keep away from light: dish contains base fish (8)

> ENSHADOW = Keep away from light. To dish is to ENDOW, which contains SHAD, a staple fish in many diets. Missing letter: D from enDow.

7.Obsolete record two girls put together (8)

9.Show how to behave... (3)

10....in Bali. By appearance, it's another country (5)

> LIBYA - hidden, no missing letters

11.Arranges incoherent ditties (6)

> TIDIES - anagram of ditties. Missing letter: T

15.Stop short de Gaulle's night of tedium (5)

> ENNUI - de Gaulle's night is EN NUIT, ended short gives ENNUI. No missing letters.

16.That is essentially wrong and inflexible (4)

17.Leader of two kings' dynasty (4)

18.Hunter versus men beheading big cat (5)

> ORION is a hunter. A big cat is LION, and beheaded is ION. I haven't figured out the "versus men" part yet. Probably has a missing letter.

19.Poisonous river overcomes me? It's what LD50 tells you (8)

> LD50 is one measure of TOXICITY. Poisonous = TOXIC, me = I, River = TYE. Missing letter: E

Down:

1.Ruling party of 8s lawyers: first one in the hot-tub is tense (8)

2.Conferencier routinely found in the middle of bull-ring (8)

3.Robust computer from 2001? (3)

> HAL is the computer from 2001. Robust is HALE. Missing letter: E.

4.Incompatible saline mixture (5)

> Incompatible is ALIEN, an anagram of SALINE minus the S. Missing letter: S.

5.Kids's informal claim to fish this way (3)

> Kids claim things using DIBS. And to DIB is a way to fish. Missing letter S.

6.Pure (no way modified) artillery (8)

> PURE NO WAY anagrammed gives WEAPONRY. Missing letter: U.

8.Middle-east gentleman bearing up in synthetic clothing(6)

> SYRIAN is middle east. An AMIR is a gentlement going up inside SYN - short for synthetic and "clothing" (around) AMIR. Missing letter: M.

12.Take away 19 using first drug introduced to first of 10 (5)

> DETOX takes away toxicity (19 across). D is first drug, MET is introduced to, O is first "of", X is 10. Missing letter: M.

13.I mind ring-tailed (twice) and short-tailed lemur(5)

> INDRI is a short-tailed lemur, which is MIND+RING, with mind "tailed" (dropping the M) and ring "tailed) (dropping the NG). Alternately, the RING is tailed twice to drop both G and N and the clue has a missing letter M, but that would be three M's in a row.

14.Timeless sequence of movements of itself (3)

17.Snap obtrusively religious recording (3)

> I think this is PIC for "Snap", but I'm not sure how it fits the rest. I'm assuming there's a missing letter.

I'm vaguely worried because I haven't found any clashes yet, though my current ending letters for 16 Across are not very nice.

Comment: 1. across is close but wrong -- you haven't used "base" and dish is easier than you're thinking :)  Everything else is right, but your reasoning for 8. down is wrong.  Deusovi's got the right explanation in his link, so won't spoil things by explaining here.